# Insert multidimensional array into multidimensional json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I want to insert some data into sub in json data with my data in database

here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pharma_data";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $row_array['id'] = $row['phar_id'];
    $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
    $row_array['batch'] = $row['batch_no'];
    $row_array['category'] = $row['category'];
    $row_array['measurement'] = $row['measurement'];
    $row_array['stock'] = $row['stock'];
    $row_array['price'] = $row['price'];
    $row_array['date'] = $row['date_added'];
    $row_array['expiration'] = $row['expiration_date'];
    $row_array['type'] = $row['medicin_type'];
    $row_array['supplier'] = $row['supplier'];
    array_push($data,$row_array);
}

$convert = json_encode($data);
echo $convert;
```

but the output of my code is:

```
[{"id":"8","name":"Test Product Name Pharmacy","batch":"Test Product Name Pharmacy","category":"Test Category Pharmacy","measurement":"1mg","stock":"2","price":"15","date":"February 18, 2021, 11:36 am","expiration":"2021-02-18","type":"Test Medicine Type Pharmacy","supplier":"Nicole Gonzaga"},{"id":"9","name":"Alaxan","batch":"Test user medicine Supplies","category":"Test Category Pharmacy","measurement":"1mg","stock":"66","price":"63.43","date":"February 28, 2021, 4:45 pm","expiration":"2021-02-28","type":"Test Medicine Type Pharmacy","supplier":"Nicole Gonzaga"},{"id":"10","name":"Medicol","batch":"987","category":"Test Category Pharmacy","measurement":"1mg","stock":"15","price":"123.23","date":"February 28, 2021, 5:42 pm","expiration":"2021-02-28","type":"Test Medicine Type Pharmacy","supplier":"Nicole Gonzaga"},{"id":"11","name":"test","batch":"test","category":"Test Category Pharmacy","measurement":"213","stock":"32","price":"123.78","date":"February 28, 2021, 6:43 pm","expiration":"2021-02-28","type":"Test Medicine Type Pharmacy","supplier":"Nicole Gonzaga"}]
```

***Want output like this:***

```
{
  "total": 800,
  "totalNotFiltered": 800,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Item 0",
      "price": "$0"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Item 1",
      "price": "$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnVsy.png)

Comment: what is the logic to calculate "total": 800,  "totalNotFiltered": 800,?

Comment: Add `echo "<pre>"` right before `echo $convert` and it should beautify the code as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out `$data` before sending it to the response so it means we need a function `myFilter` to filter the `$data` elements and we can filter all the elements in the array using `array_map()`. The `total` and `totalFiltered` column seems to give the total number of rows in `$data` hence the `count()`. Try the code below:

```
function myFilter($a) {
    $row['id'] = $a['id'];
    $row['name'] = $a['name'];
    $row['price'] = $a['price'];
   return $row;
};

$filterData = array(
    'total' => count($data),
    'totalNotFiltered' => count($data),
    'rows' => array_map("myFilter", $data)
);

$convert = json_encode($filterData);
echo $convert;
```

Demo code would be here: https://ideone.com/pZCUbG

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the returned data. Something like:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $row_array['id'] = $row['phar_id'];
    $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
    // $row_array['batch'] = $row['batch_no'];
    // $row_array['category'] = $row['category'];
    // $row_array['measurement'] = $row['measurement'];
    // $row_array['stock'] = $row['stock'];
    $row_array['price'] = $row['price'];
    // $row_array['date'] = $row['date_added'];
    // $row_array['expiration'] = $row['expiration_date'];
    // $row_array['type'] = $row['medicin_type'];
    // $row_array['supplier'] = $row['supplier'];
    $data[] = $row_array; // Same as array_push($data,$row_array);
}

$final_data = array(
    'total' => count($data),
    'totalNotFiltered' => '',
    'rows' => $data
);

$convert = json_encode($final_data);
echo $convert;
```

Commented out the data that isn't needed in this context (maybe you need it to use elsewhere, not sure. If so just uncomment back)

Not sure with `totalNotFiltered` as I don't know how you are calculating this. Maybe you can work with that and this gives you an idea to work with.